# Get HTML string from web in C#, but does not contain data part

Tags: c#, html, parsing, uwp, web-crawler

I'm trying to get a data from webpage(https://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_trans_style.nhn) In my UWP App.
I write following source code in my project.

```
public class MainPageViewModel : Observable
{
    public string urlAddress = "https://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_trans_style.nhn";
    public string data { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClick = new RelayCommand(Click);
    }

    public async void Click()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(urlAddress));
        data = result;
        OnPropertyChanged("data");
    }
    public RelayCommand ButtonClick { get; set; }
}
```

But, the problem is, **I'm not getting document's data part**. following picture depicts the part of docs that I want to get.
[image: the part that i want to get]

In "data" variable, I get docs without data the most important part to me. I can get just other html parts.

I was trying to figure out where data are coming from, or which source helps me to get data. but I failed.
Are the data made from javascript? .. ajax... and,, how can I get data from that web page? .. And if I encounter this kind of problems next time, how can I figure out the reason?

#### (EDIT)Added HTML Source. and more specified.

when I see HTML DOCS with my source, I can get following contents.

```
<div class="box_type_m">
    <iframe name="time" src="/sise/investorDealTrendTime.nhn?bizdate=20181005&sosok=" width="100%"  height="380" marginheight="0" bottommargin="0" topmargin="0" SCROLLING="no" frameborder="0" title="시간별 순매수"></iframe>
</div>
```

but iframe has another html source ( contatining head & body).

Comment: It looks from the image like it's either contained in an iframe, or it's dynamic content loaded via javascript. If it's via an iframe, you'd need to load the content of that iframe URL. If it's dynamic, scraping would be considerably more complicated and would require some kind of headless browser to actually execute the javascript.

Comment: if page is updated using JS you will not see that in http request as HTTPClient is not a web browser, if you want JS to execute try something like chrome headless

Comment: I get the part you are asking using your code.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Yes, I was editing my Post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you want is in iframes.  These are loaded as pages within the page.  You can see this in the source.

The actual URLs you should check out are:

- https://ssl.pstatic.net/imgfinance/chart/sise/trendUitradeDayKOSPI.png?sid=1538753584555
- https://finance.naver.com/sise/investorDealTrendTime.nhn?bizdate=20181005&sosok=
- https://finance.naver.com/sise/investorDealTrendDay.nhn?bizdate=20181005&sosok=

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem with your hint. I get iframe's src attribute value, and I use it as url. Exactly, I can get what I want.